# How can we derive $u_0 (t) = a_0 \cos (\omega_0 t + a_0)$ from this solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading the

*Mason, D. P.*, [**On the method of strained parameters and the method of averaging**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/qam/736507), Q. Appl. Math. 42, 77-85 (1984). [ZBL0545.70033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0545.70033)

and on page $79$ solves the very trivial differential equation
\begin{align}
\ddot{u_0}+ \omega_{0}^{2} u_0 = 0
\end{align}
and gets the solution $u_0(t) = a_0 \cos (\omega_0 t + a_0)$. But how? It's supposed to be solved by characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + \omega_0^{2} = 0 \implies \lambda = \pm w_0 i$ which in turn give
\begin{align}
u_0 (t)= C_1 \sin (\omega t) + C_2 \cos(\omega t)
\end{align}
what am I missing?

Comment: You can combine a linear combination of sines and cosines into a single shifted cosine wave quite easily, see: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yit6iha6xh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misread the paper slightly, there are two constants in the general solution,
$$ u_0(t) = a_0\cos(\omega_0 t + \underset{\uparrow}{\alpha_0})$$

This is equivalent to the form you got by the [angle addition formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)
$ \cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A \sin B$, which gives
$$ u_0(t) = (a_0 \cos \alpha_0 )\cos\omega_0t - (a_0\sin\alpha_0)\sin \omega_0t$$
so $$C_1 = a_0 \cos\alpha_0, \quad C_2 = -a_0 \sin\alpha_0$$
or,
$$ a_0 = \sqrt{C_1^2 + C_2^2},\quad  \alpha_0=\arccos \frac{C_1}{\sqrt{C_1^2 + C_2^2}}$$

Comment: Absolutely correct, and horrible choice of notation in part of the original paper's author.

Comment: @algevristis yes, i have read many older papers with this problem...I think it probably was clearer in the original handwriting